# What's the meaning of "bust head open"

Tags: phrases

What's the meaning of the bold part

> You want me **to bust your head open?**

I added the scene's picture from the movie (The fighter) to decribe the question better

[image]

Comment: Literally, "*break* your head open." Figuratively, "give you a good beating."

Answer (score 2):

> bust your head *(wide)* open

is an idiomatic expression meaning to beat you up and give you a good pounding such that your head breaks open (figuratively).

Breaking a skull is a nontrivial matter.

> [Quoting a bike-helmet study published in the Journal of Neurosurgery: Pediatrics, he wrote that 235 kg (520 pounds) or 2,300 newtons of force would be needed to crush a human skull, almost twice as much force as human hands could possibly muster.](http://www.sciencealert.com/game-of-thrones-exposed-the-science-of-skull-crushing)

Which is fairly significant.

Answer (score 0):

You want me "to bust your head open"?

The man who is speaking threateningly is a boxer.  The phrase means to break your head open by giving hitting or punching it.